# Package Name Conflict in custom Libraries on weblogic server

Tags: java, ejb, weblogic

I am facing this unique problem, i have some custom libraries deployed in weblogic lib folder and some of them have same package structure and even some classes have same names. But these libraries are being used in different applications, so applications dont give any compile time error. But in a shared environment, they are causing trouble. Any suggestion on how to fix this with minimum changes. I am using weblogic 11 server and working with EJB 3.0 applications.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is at level of design. A good library or application should have a custom package not reused by other libraries or applications.

The best solution is to refactoring your code changing the package names. Don't limit the changes to the conflicting classes, but change the whole package. It should be simple with modern ide (Eclipse, IntelliJ).

For next projects remember to use always a syntax for packages like the following

```
com.yourcompany.yourproject.specificpackages
```

this will guarantee that no class will go in conflict with others.

Comment: :) looks like the previous developers forget to add the "YourProject" part, thanks by the way, but i am looking for more of a 'addon' kind of approch rather then a 'Start from Scratch' approch.

Comment: Is not a start from scratch. Open the project, select the package, go the menu refactor->rename and change the name of the package.